# Customize google maps marker in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to customize the icon marker, but when I link to my custom image (inside wordpress) it doesn't work. When I do it out of wordpress it works.
I think I need some special wordpress request in my script.js..

```
var image1 = 'map-marker.png';
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.4015659, 2.1564281);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          icon: image1
      });
```

Comment: Did you tried it with an absolute path? 
something like this: http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/map-marker.png

Comment: it works, but I'm not sure that it is the right way..

Comment: Well, of course you could use a relative path.`var image1 =` needs to be a valid path to an image. It doesn't matter if its absolute or relative.